# External resource in jsfiddle is undefined

Tags: javascript, git, jsfiddle

I have made this github repo https://github.com/hollowdoor/dom_autoscroller_demo

For some reason this jsfiddle referencing the repo doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/hollowdoor/dom_autoscroller_demo/tree/master/Demo

The external resources are left undefined.

I have looked at other answers on stackoverflow, and none of those seem to address my specific problem.

```
let wtf = "stack overflow doesn't like jsfiddle without code?"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a redirect on the external resouce that loads the dragula library.

It would seem JS Fiddle doesn't follow it.

Updating the resource to the redirected link works.

i.e. Using https://unpkg.com/dragula@3.7.2/dist/dragula.js instead of https://unpkg.com/dragula/dist/dragula.js

http://jsfiddle.net/3q9wjc2s/1/

```
Yep, StackOverflow isn't suited to debugging issues with JSFiddle itself 
in situations like this due to the necessary protections against links.
```

Comment: I thought that might be it, but it did work once before with the redirects. That's why I didn't try it without the redirects. Maybe the non-redirect file was in the cache, or something.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Though there is still a problem. The external resources don't work on first load for some reason. They work if I click run on the fiddle. It's a problem I can't really solve so I put the links in the html. This gives an XSS warning for noscript, but it does work.